# How to make CommitBlocking commit ? -- Google Play Game Services

Tags: c++11, cocos2d-x, google-play-games

I was doing a little game using cocos2d-x for android. I am currently struggling to implement Cloud Save for my game. The only problem left is that it does not commit.

The GPGS API I am using is C++. Just scroll down to the commitblocking there.

```
//using sample codes from Google.
game_services->Snapshots().Open
(
    "some_save_file",
    gpg::SnapshotConflictPolicy::MANUAL,
    [this, &save](gpg::SnapshotManager::OpenResponse const& response)
    {
        LOGI("Saving snapshot");
        if(gpg::IsSuccess(response.status))
        {
            LOGI("Open success");
            gpg::SnapshotMetadata metadata = response.data;
            if (response.conflict_id != "")
            {
                //Conflict detected
                //Settle conflict
            }

            LOGI("Getting PNG data");
            //get cover image data
            //some code to get png data in to png_vector

            LOGI("Building snapshot builder");
            //setting up the builder
            gpg::SnapshotMetadataChange::Builder builder;
            gpg::SnapshotMetadataChange metadata_change =
                    builder
                    .SetDescription("Recall Save File")
                    .SetCoverImageFromPngData(png_vector)
                    .Create();

          LOGI("Commiting");
          // Save the snapshot.
          // This is the part that does not work !!!!!
          gpg::SnapshotManager::CommitResponse commitResponse =
              game_services->Snapshots().CommitBlocking(gpg::Timeout(3000), response.data, metadata_change, save);

          if (IsSuccess(commitResponse.status))
            CSH_LOGI("Saved game");
          else
            CSH_LOGI("Saved game failed error: %d", commitResponse.status);
    }
);
```

When compiled and running on phone :

```
    06-25 16:51:47.405: V/GamesNativeSDK(10717): Snapshot was not committed, discarding.
    06-25 16:51:47.410: V/GamesNativeSDK(10717): Snapshot discard complete.
```

I had tried with Commit(), which crash the game, and CommitBlocking() with no timeout, it doesn't commit too.

I spent almost a week on this problem looking at the documentation and samples. So, anyone met this problem before ? If do, do share with me how to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you enable the the snapshots first, using [EnableSnapshots()](https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/savedgames#enabling_the_savedgames_service) ?

Check the full [C++ save implementation](https://github.com/playgameservices/cpp-android-basic-samples/blob/master/samples-android/CollectAllTheStarsNative/src/main/jni/CollectAllTheStarsNativeActivity.cpp) sample in Github. It will help you a lot.

Comment: Yeah I did. I found some bugs and solved them. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there were some weird bugs.

1)A method to return save as a std::vector save to be used in CommitBlocking only returns a vector with zero size.

2)The Png data was too big to be accepted by Google Cloud Save.

After getting the method stated in 1) to return correct data and minimizing and looseless compressing the Png used in 2) do solve the problem.